# Sql query to get rows which have a column with multiple values at the same time

Tags: sql, join, select

I have three tables: *POST*, *POST_ROLE* and *ROLE* which portion of them is as below. *POST* and *ROLE* have a many to many relation and their join table is *POST_ROLE*.

How to get posts which have different roles at the same time?

For example, how to get posts which Have roles *ROLE_USER* and *ROLE_ADMIN* at the same time?

A query as below, doesn't return anything, because a row can't have two values for one column:

```sql
SELECT
    *
FROM
    POST op
JOIN POST_ROLE opr ON
    op.POST_ID = opr.POST_ID
JOIN ROLE or1 ON
    opr.ROLE_ID = or1.ROLE_ID
WHERE
    or1.CODE = 'ROLE_USER' AND or1.CODE = 'ROLE_ADMIN';
```

Another query which use **IN** operator, retun all three post rows, because **IN** operation works as **OR** operator here.

```sql
SELECT
    *
FROM
    POST op
JOIN POST_ROLE opr ON
    op.POST_ID = opr.POST_ID
JOIN ROLE or1 ON
    opr.ROLE_ID = or1.ROLE_ID
WHERE
    or1.CODE IN ('ROLE_USER','ROLE_ADMIN');
```

The preferred result of query should be something as below:

| POST_ID | TITLE | ROLE_ID | CODE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | CEO | 100 | ROLE_USER |
| 1 | CEO | 101 | ROLE_ADMIN |

POST table:

| POST_ID | TITLE |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | CEO |
| 2 | CTO |

ROLE table:

| ROLE_ID | CODE |
| --- | --- |
| 100 | ROLE_USER |
| 101 | ROLE_ADMIN |
| 102 | ROLE_ANONYMOUS |

POST_ROLE table:

| POST_ID | ROLE_ID |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 |
| 1 | 101 |
| 2 | 101 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is:

```sql
SELECT
    *
FROM
    POST p
WHERE
    EXISTS (
    SELECT
        1
    FROM
        POST_ROLE pr
    JOIN ROLE r ON
        r.ROLE_ID = pr.ROLE_ID
    WHERE
        p.POST_ID = pr.POST_ID
        AND r.CODE = 'ROLE_USER')
    AND EXISTS (
    SELECT
        1
    FROM
        POST_ROLE pr
    JOIN ROLE r ON
        r.ROLE_ID = pr.ROLE_ID
    WHERE
        p.POST_ID = pr.POST_ID
        AND r.CODE = 'ROLE_ADMIN');
```